# Resizing shape of collision object in Game Object Script

Tags: lua, game-development, defold

I am having a game object.

[image: Game object Property]

I am increasing the size of the game object using game logic by setting the scale of the game object, however I am not able to change the size of the box of the collision object. Is there an API reference document or a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for physics scaling was added today in Defold 1.2.170. Read more in the release notes: https://forum.defold.com/t/defold-1-2-170-has-been-released/65631

You need to check the Allow Dynamic Transforms option in game.project to enable this feature.